# Longest sequence of consecutive letters

Tags: python, sequence

Suppose I have a string of lower case letters, e.g.

```
'ablccmdnneofffpg'
```

And my aim is to find the longest sequence of the consecutive numbers inside this string which in this case is:

```
'abcdefg'
```

The intuitive attempt is to find loop around each letter and obtain the longest sequence starting from that letter. One possible solution is

```
longest_length = 0
start = None
current_start = 0
while current_start < len(word) - longest_length:
    current_length = 1
    last_in_sequence = ord(word[current_start])
    for i in range(current_start + 1, len(word)):
        if ord(word[i]) - last_in_sequence == 1:
            current_length += 1
            last_in_sequence = ord(word[i])
    if current_length > longest_length:
        longest_length = current_length
        start = current_start
    while (current_start < len(word) - 1 and
           ord(word[current_start + 1]) - ord(word[current_start]) == 1):
        current_start += 1
    current_start += 1
```

Are there any other ways of solving the problem with fewer lines, or even using some pythonic methods?

Comment: Do you want to find the _longest sequence_, or the _length_ of such a sequence?

Comment: Your algorithm uses cpu cycles. You could keep track of all possible sequences at once and then only iterate once trading memory for cpu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keep track of all subsequences of consecutive characters as seen in the string using a dictionary, and then take the one with the largest length.

Each subsequence is *keyed* by the next candidate in the alphabet so that once the anticipated candidate is reached in the string, it is used to update the value of the corresponding subsequence in the dictionary and added as a new dictionary value *keyed* by the next alphabet:

```
def longest_sequence(s):
    d = {}
    for x in s:
       if x in d:
           d[chr(ord(x)+1)] = d[x] + x
       else:
           d[chr(ord(x)+1)] = x
    return max(d.values(), key=len)

print(longest_sequence('ablccmdnneofffpg'))
# abcdefg
print(longest_sequence('ba'))
# b
print(longest_sequence('sblccmtdnneofffpgtuyvgmmwwwtxjyuuz'))
# stuvwxyz
```

Comment: @DSM Updated. Tested on `"ba"` (gives `'b'` or `'a'`; ordering can be fixed with an `OrderedDict`) and a host of others.

Comment: Good solution, had the same approach when I saw the problem. `max(v for v in d.values())` is the same as `max(d.values())`, btw.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I don't think it's the same. `max(d.values())` checks `max` per character, not length.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I understand you have a key function in your max call! I left that out for simplicity ;) still your generator expression iterates through all elements in `d.values()`. You might just pass `d.values()` itself...

Comment: @schwobaseggl Haha, thanks. I had modified a nested expression to get to that.  *laughing at myself now*

Comment: Thank you very much @MosesKoledoye, your method is very neat and quite understandable.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that trades memory for (some) time:

It keeps track of all sequences seen and then at the end prints the longest found (although there could be more than one).

```
from contextlib import suppress


class Sequence:
    def __init__(self, letters=''):
        self.letters = letters
        self.last = self._next_letter(letters[-1:])

    def append(self, letter):
        self.letters += letter
        self.last = self._next_letter(letter)

    def _next_letter(self, letter):
        with suppress(TypeError):
            return chr(ord(letter) + 1)
        return 'a'

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Sequence({}, {})'.format(repr(self.letters),
                                         repr(self.last))


word = 'ablccmdnneofffpg'
sequences = []
for letter in word:
    for s in sequences:
        if s.last == letter:
            s.append(letter)
            break
    else:
        sequences.append(Sequence(letters=letter))

sequences = list(sorted(sequences, key=lambda s: len(s.letters), reverse=True))
print(sequences[0].letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking for the `longest increasing subsequence`, which is a well-studied problem. Have a look at the [pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Not quite. `abfh`is an increasing subsequence but doesn't satisfy OP's condition that it must consist of *consecutive* letters. On the other hand, it is clearly related to the `longest increasing subsequence` problem, and the corresponding algorithms could be tweaked for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [MosesKoledoye's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125566/moses-koledoye) solution, but only stores the lengthes for the ordinals of the chars and only builts the solution string in the end. This should therefore be a little more space-efficient:

```
def longest_seq(s):
  d = {}
  for c in s:
    c, prev_c = ord(c), ord(c) - 1
    d[c] = max(d.get(c, 0), d.pop(prev_c, 0) + 1)
  c, l = max(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
  return ''.join(map(chr, range(c-l+1, c+1)))
```